# Tomcat app behind an Apache subdomain - virtualhost error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, subdomain, virtualhost

I need to have 2 application on Tomcat behind apache virtualhost. Each app gave own domain.
There are my apache virtualhost configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tomcat.example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tomcat.example.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>         
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>   

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tomcat.example.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>    
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/domain.tld/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>
```

By default, all app are accesible through http://tomcat.example.net/APPNAME - it is ok.

Second virtualhost is for app with domain *domain.tld*.

If I go to app through http://tomcat.example.net/domain.tld/info/ it works good but if I go throug http://domain.tld/ and click on links on page all links link to http://domain.tld/domain.tld/info/ - I see error page.

In JSP page I use *c:url* so it maybe be good.

```
<c:url value="/info/" />
```

I use default tomcat7 settings on ubuntu 12.04 server.

---

App on subdomain has subdomain/appName in url. On subdomain it is  http://domain.tld/APPNAME/info/ (http://domain.tld/domain.tld/info/) but it must be only http://domain.tld/info/ domain.tld=APPNAME

How to config apache/tomcat/my app?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to config apache/tomcat/my app. App on subdomain has subdomain/appName in url. On subdomain it is  http://domain.tld/domain.tld/info/ but it must be only http://domain.tld/info/